How do I formalize a repeated relationship among disjoint groups of classes in python?
I have Python code that has the following shape to it:
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo_Data:
    foo: int


class Foo_Processor:
    def process(self, data: Foo_Data): ...


class Foo_Loader:
    def load(self, file_path: str) -> Foo_Data: ...

#----------------------------------------------------------------

@dataclass
class Bar_Data:
    bar: str


class Bar_Processor:
    def process(self, data: Bar_Data): ...


class Bar_Loader:
    def load(self, file_path: str) -> Bar_Data: ...

I have several instances of this sort of Data/Processor/Loader setup, and the classes all have the same method signatures modulo the specific class family (Foo, Bar, etc.). Is there a pythonic way of formalizing this relationship among classes to enforce a similar structure if I decide to create a Spam_Data, Spam_Processor, and Spam_Loader family of classes? For instance, I want something to enforce that Spam_Processor have a process method which takes an argument of type Spam_Data. Is there a way of achieving this standardization somehow with abstract classes, generic types, or some other structure?
I tried using abstract classes, but mypy correctly points out that having all *_Data classes be subclasses of an abstract Data class and similarly having all *_Processor classes be subclasses of an abstract Processor class violates the Liskov substitution principle, since each processor is only designed for its respective Data class (i.e., Foo_Processor can't process Bar_Data, but one would expect that it could if these classes have superclasses Processor and Data which are compatible in this way).

Can you combine each _Processor, _Loader and _Data class? You could the use an abstract base class to define the relationships. Something like myclass as an ABC with load and process as abstract methods, then class Foo(myclass) and define the specific data, load and process methods in there.

Why, e.g., is Foo_Processor a class in the first place, instead of a simple process_foo function?

I simplified the code to try to make my question clear and to make it easy for others with a similar situation to find/understand. @PaulWilson, @chepner, I didn't include other code/files which would have helped show that other code can produce instances of Foo_Data, and also Foo_Processor actually has attributes that are set and then used for processing. This is why I chose to keep these all separate and as classes rather than functions.

You can use abstract base classes (ABCs) with Generics. This way you can define a common interface while ensuring type safety:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

# generic type variable for Data
T = TypeVar('T', bound='BaseData')


@dataclass
class BaseData(ABC):
    pass


class BaseProcessor(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def process(self, data: T) -> None:
        pass


class BaseLoader(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def load(self, file_path: str) -> T:
        pass

Now you can define your specific classes
@dataclass
class Foo_Data(BaseData):
    foo: int


class Foo_Processor(BaseProcessor[Foo_Data]):
    def process(self, data: Foo_Data) -> None: ...


class Foo_Loader(BaseLoader[Foo_Data]):
    def load(self, file_path: str) -> Foo_Data: ...


@dataclass
class Bar_Data(BaseData):
    bar: str


class Bar_Processor(BaseProcessor[Bar_Data]):
    def process(self, data: Bar_Data) -> None: ...


class Bar_Loader(BaseLoader[Bar_Data]):
    def load(self, file_path: str) -> Bar_Data: ...

Writing your code this way combines the benefits of a common interface with type safety.

ABCs ensure that subclasses implement required methods, promoting a consistent structure.

Generics allow for type-specific operations, enhancing code readability and maintainability.


As a confirmation with mypy:
mypy script.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file


This was very helpful, thank you so much! What would you recommend I do if the repeated structure also has subclasses, i.e, each family has a Special_Data class that inherits from its Data class, but also has a string attribute called extra_info? I'm trying to figure out how to make a Base_Special_Data class such that I can define the Foo_Special_Data class and have it inherit everything from Foo_Data and also automatically gain the extra_info attribute (and have this generalize to Bar, Spam, and so on).

@AlexDuchnowski If I understood it correctly, you can do it by creating a BaseSpecialData class that inherits from BaseData and includes the extra_info attribute. Then, you can create specific Special_Data classes that inherit from both their respective Data classes and BaseSpecialData.
